# If I upgrade my sandbox, will the program disappear?

Tags: sandbox, update

I will update Salesforce for the first time.

If I update my sandbox after upgrading Salesforce, will ApexClass and LightningComponent disappear?

What should I do to keep the program from disappearing?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean refresh your sandbox  when you say update?

Comment: @sanketkumar yes. I want to use summer'19.
By upgrading Salesforce and refreshing the sandbox, I can develop with the latest version.
Am I wrong?　thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the org already been upgraded to summer 19 by now. If you want fresh metadata from your target org, off course you can refresh it. It will replace your existing metadata, so you need to take backup of your apex classes and Lightning Component before refresh. Or you will loose it.

Read more here:- [Create, Clone, or Refresh a Sandbox](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_create_parent.htm&type=5)

Comment: thank you for your kindness!!

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a sandbox it will make a copy of either your production org or another Sandbox. I recommend using something like Github as the place where your codebase lives and not your production org.

Then you can refresh a sandbox, clone your git repo and deploy your work in the sandbox or scratch org.

Comment: thank you for your kindness!!